# Instantiate an extended class or its parent (depending on circumstances)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class named `Human` in `ProjectA`. It is instantiated in the `CreatureBuilder` class of the same project.

Now I want to create a new class called `Cyborg` in a different project, i.e. in `ProjectB`. `ProjectB` has `ProjectA` in its imports, but `ProjectA` knows nothing about `ProjectB`.

`Cyborg extends Human`, and must also be instantiated by `CreatureBuilder` of `ProjectA` (so, `Cyborg` is located in `ProjectB`, I call `CreatureBuilder` from `ProjectB` to instantiate `Cyborg`, but `CreatureBuilder` is located in `ProjectA`, as well as my `Human` class).

I need a logic to create a `Human` when `CreatureBuilder` is instantiated from `ProjectA`, and to create a `Cyborg` when `CreatureBuilder` is instantiated from `ProjectB`.

I think it is achievable by creating an interface with a `getCreature()` method in `ProjectA`. This method will be overridden in `ProjectB` to `return new Cyborg` and then passed back to `CreatureBuilder` of `ProjectA`.
Any other suggestions? What do you think is the best workaround? Can I use reflection API instead?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it, but why not use two different CreatureBuilder classes in the two projects?

Comment: @FrankPuffer Well, "CreatureBuilder" is a huge class, like 5k lines of code or more. Its logic may change in the future, so if I follow the copy-paste route I will have to update both implementations.

Comment: You do not neccessarily copy/paste the whole code, just put the common stuff into a common base class.

Answer (score 5):

### Java 8

`CreatureBuilder` can delegate the creature's creation to the caller by asking for a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

```
public class CreatureBuilder {
    public Creature getCreature(Supplier<Creature> creatureSupplier)
    {
        //do some unknown things
        return creatureSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Usage from ProjectA

```
public class ProjectA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Creature A = new CreatureBuilder().getCreature(Human::new);
    }
}
```

Usage from ProjectB

```
public class ProjectB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Creature B = new CreatureBuilder().getCreature(Cyborg::new);
    }
}
```

And never use reflection if you're not forced to.

### Java 7

If you're sticked with Java 7, the principle remains the same except that it's a bit more verbose.

You have to declare and use your own Supplier-like interface

```
public interface CreatureSupplier {
    Creature get();
}

public class CreatureBuilder {
    public Creature getCreature(CreatureSupplier creatureSupplier)
    {
        //do some things
        return creatureSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Usage is a bit more verbose

```
public class ProjectA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Creature A = new CreatureBuilder().getCreature(new CreatureSupplier() {
            @Override
            public Creature get() {
                return new Human();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class ProjectB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Creature B = new CreatureBuilder().getCreature(new CreatureSupplier() {
            @Override
            public Creature get() {
                return new Cyborg();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And... that's it, you've got the same behaviour as the one in Java 8.

Comment: Thank you! Great example, probably the best workaround available in 2016. But I can't upgrade current project's platform to Java 8, unfortunately... Gotta stick to solutions compatible with 1.7 for now.

Comment: @Zhiroslav I updated my answer with a Java 7 equivalent example.

Comment: How this is different from below for Java 7 except for verbosity, also you need to be able to create differnt objects by passing in a type not just Human, Cyborg.

Comment: @Spotted Thank you. Btw, you previously mentioned reflection. I will avoid using it, but do you know how this can be done via reflection API?

Comment: @svasa by "below", do you mean your answer ?

Comment: @Zhiroslav As I try to avoid using reflection in my code (I was forced to use it only twice in 2 years), I'm don't know how to achieve this with it, sorry.

Comment: @Spotted, yes below means that.

Comment: @svasa the difference is who has the responsibility to instanciate new creatures. In your solution, it's the factory. In my solution, it's the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at factory pattern. Yes you can do it with an interface and a factory class in project A and a factory class in B that extends it.

Example:

In Project A:

```
public interface CreatureBuilder
{
   Creature getCreature(String type);
}

public class Creature
{
   //fields of Creature class
}

public class Human extends Creature
{
  //fields of Human
}

public class Ape extends Creature
{
  //fields of Ape
}



public class ProjectAFactory implements CreatureBuilder
{
   @Override
   public Creature getCreature( String type )
   {
      switch(type)
      {
         case("Human"): return new Human();
         case("Ape") : return new Ape();
         default : return null;
      }
   }
}
```

You can call `ProjectAFactory.getCreature("Human");` to create Human object

Then in project B

```
public class ProjectBFactory extends ProjectAFactory
{
    @Override
    public Creature getCreature(String type)
    {
       switch(type)
       {
          case ( "Cyborg" ) : return new Cyborg();
          default : return super.getCreature(type);
       }
    }

}


public class Cyborg extends Creature
{
   //fields related to Cyborg which also fields of Creature in project A
}
```

You can call `ProjectBFactory.getCreature("Cyborg");` to create Cyborg or even `ProjectBFactory.getCreature("Human")` to get a Human Object.